# Como salvar posição da barra de rolagem?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Gostaria de obter a posição da barra de rolagem do `DataGridView`, para que após dar um *refresh*, continue na mesma posição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então cara, pra você pegar qual a posição do scroll

```
 int currentPositionScroll = datagridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
```

e aqui é para você setar o valor que quer para o scroll

```
datagridView.FirstDisplayScrollingRowIndex = currentPositionScroll
```

Espero que ajude.